# Give scrollbar to body of table

Tags: html, html-table

My table is in the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zj36whmo/

```html
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
            <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
```

I want to give the tbody alone a scrollbar. I have seen many questions on stackoverflow to make the tbody alone scroll. However, they mess with the width. I tried tinkering with the options but I lose the scroll. Please help me

Comment: check this one [Fixed Table Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071546/fixed-table-header)

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on comment looking for alignment, note that many things changed and jQuery code has been added for proper resizing. It's an adaptation of the [suggested question in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody) to your case.

```js
var $table = $('table'),
  $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
  colWidth;

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Get the tbody columns width array
  colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
  }).get();

  // Set the width of thead columns
  $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
  });
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
table tbody,
table thead {
  display: block;
}
thead tr th {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  /* text-align: left; */
}
table tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
tbody {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}
tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}
tbody td:last-child,
thead th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford test</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue more</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Hi, the header is correct. but the rows are thinner than the header

Comment: The problem is that I generate the content dynamically

Comment: @Echchama edited to a more complex scenario considering alignment and resizing, note that you might still have to tweak a few values here and there to fit your real content. Hope helps.